# Are include an exclude really required on tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript

I just migrated an old project to use vite + typescript.
Previously this project had a tsconfig.json file to get intellisense on the javascript files, the tsconfig file looked like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "rootReducer": ["common/rootReducer"],
      "@common/*": ["common/*"],
      "formatters": ["formatters"],
      "@types": ["types"]
    }
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "node_modules/**"]
}
```

However, when I moved everything to TS my VSCode instance was sloppy, not able to do automatic imports and the type checking was continuously failing, showing out of date errors etc. To try to diagnose the problem I renamed the old tsconfig file to be `tsconfig.old` and started a new file from scratch using `tsc --init`.
To my surprise, things works now as they should and I didn't added the `include` or `exclude` sections. Are those two sections actually needed? tsc is not performing any compilation, everything is handled by the bundler, and the bundler doesn't seem to need them either, so... Are those two properties an actual requirement for all projects? Or just for those that use tsc to compile?

Comment: [TSConfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) is written for and used by the TypeScript compiler. If another program uses your `tsconfig.json`, the implementation of that usage is entirely up to the other software, whether that's a text editor or a bundler, etc. Each program's documentation (and definitely its source code) should clarify how it uses config files.

Comment: good point. I'll see what VSCode docs says about TSConfig. However, I also use tsc to check type errors and it works fine without exclude and include too